# Slots vue 3 with bootsrap modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, bootstrap-modal, vuejs3

How i can change button in show modal.

ModalForm component:

```
<b-modal centered  hide-footer id="my-modal">
 <slot name="save"></slot>
</b-modal>
```

Component one:

```
<modal-form>
<template #save>
 Save
</template>
</modal-form>
```

Component two:

```
<modal-form>
<template #save>
 Edit
</template>
</modal-form>
```

If i do this button **is save**

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem in this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue2-bootstrap-vue-vite-starter-im4u4e?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FModalForm.vue). Can you fork that to create a reproduction?

Comment: @tony19 dont work with boostrap-vue-3